# Checking for shared folder write access for current user

Tags: c#, permissions, c#-2.0

I have following method to check current user have write access to given network location

```
DirectorySecurity shareSecurity = new DirectoryInfo(this.GetFileServerRootPath).GetAccessControl();

foreach (FileSystemAccessRule fsRule in shareSecurity.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(NTAccount)))
{
    // check write permission for current user
    if (AccessControlType.Allow == fsRule.AccessControlType &&
            FileSystemRights.Write == (fsRule.FileSystemRights & FileSystemRights.Write))
    {
        if (null != fsRule.IdentityReference &&
            fsRule.IdentityReference.Value == WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
return false;
```

but problem is when folder permission given to user group, above method is failed.

**I don't want to check the permissions by writing a file and decide the write access permissions.**

is there any way to find current user in the `IdentityReference.Value`? or suggestions to overcome this issue?

Comment: I guess it returns false due to this part: `fsRule.IdentityReference.Value == WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name`

Comment: Yes, when `fsRule.IdentityReference.Value` is a group I need to check whether user is a member of that group or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work for you:

```
FileIOPermission writePermission = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Write, this.GetFileServerRootPath);

try
{
    writePermission.Demand();
    return true;
}
catch (SecurityException s)
{
    return false;
}
```

Just curious - why not just try/catch your write operation?

Answer (score 0):

May be you should use DirectoryInfo on that directory to get its security policies.